# Extracting URL link using regular expression re - string matching - Python

Tags: python, string, url, matching, extract

I've been trying to extract URLs from a text file using re api. any link that starts with http:// , https:// and www.

the file contains texts as well as html source code, html part is easy because i can extract them using BeautifulSoup, but normal text seems to be more challenging.
I found this online which seems to be the best implementation of URL extraction however it fails on certain tags, specially it can't handle  tags and includes them in the URL.
any help is appreciated, because I'm not familiar with string matching at all myself

here is the signature

```
sp1=re.findall("http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+", str(STRING))
sp2=re.findall('www.(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', str(STRING))
```

examples:

```
http://www.website.com/science/</span></a><o:p></o:p></span></div><div
www.website.com/library/</span></a></span></i><span
http://awebsite.com/Groups</a><div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
re.findall(r'https?://[^\s<>"]+|www\.[^\s<>"]+', str(STRING))
```

The `[^\s<>"]+` part matches any non-whitespace, non quote, non anglebracket character to avoid matching strings like:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/stuff">
http://www.example.com/stuff</br>
```