# Strip everything but URL from a string in python

Tags: python, string

I'm grabbing a series of links from a website with python and BS4 but i need to clean them up so I only get the URL in the string.

the links i get look like this:

> javascript:changeChannel('http://some-server.com/with1234init.also', 20);

and i need it to look like this

> http://some-server.com/with1234init.also

Comment: what is your attempt?

Comment: Are all strings of the exact same format, or are there corner cases in the HTML that may cause simple rules to fail?

Comment: I forgot to mention that all the links i grab is different. They all start with the javascript:changeChannel(' part but the urls are different and the end after the last ' is also different in all of the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if all the links are like that one you can do it with a very simple approach:

```
s.split("'")[1]
```

For example:

```
>>>s="javascript:changeChannel('http://some-server.com/with1234init.also', 20);"
>>>s.split("'")
['javascript:changeChannel(',
 'http://some-server.com/with1234init.also',
 ', 20);']
```

Comment: True, and I was about to post this, however, it does not give you something exact. Perhaps, you can do this and _then_ do a search with a regex to determine the index value.

Comment: Well, if all the strings are formatted the same this will probably work well for everyone. What is the case you say is not exact?

Comment: For example, there couple be more than just 2 single quotes in the line. In essence, this solution will only work for this problem but does not solve the issue at large.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac you're right. The solution is very domain specific. I explained in the answer that all strings _needed_ to be with the same format. But if they are, I think is worth doing it because is very simple.

Comment: Indeed, but I was hoping you knew some way to capture a URL (heh) using regex. I've been trying to make one myself, but I fail most of the time.

Comment: URL matching regex is huge. I thought about it but due to the simplicity of the environment I suggested this kind of _naive_ approach :)

Comment: @GamesBrainiac does my answer with a regex not work? All I got for the 1 min google was a single downvote :P

Comment: @jozxyqk I'm afraid it does not, did you just copy it from gskinner's regexr?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Works fine for me (python 2.7.5). Copied near-verbatim form [here](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls). I had to escape the `'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 str = javascript:changeChannel('http://some-server.com/with1234init.also', 20);
 formattedtext  ="http://" + str.split("http://")[1].split(',')[0].strip("'")
```

Answer (score 0):

A reasonably robust way is to take your chunk of text and search it with a URL-matching regex pattern.

See also:

- [Python regular expression again - match url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718633/python-regular-expression-again-match-url) 
  which links to here: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls
- [Extracting URL link using regular expression re - string matching - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475027/extracting-url-link-using-regular-expression-re-string-matching-python)

Using regex...

```
import re
re.search(pattern, text)
... or
re.findall(pattern, text)
```

A full example...

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))')
or
>>> p = re.compile('(?i)\\b((?:https?://|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:\\\'".,<>?\xc2\xab\xc2\xbb\xe2\x80\x9c\xe2\x80\x9d\xe2\x80\x98\xe2\x80\x99]))')

>>> m = p.search("javascript:changeChannel('http://some-server.com/with1234init.also', 20);")
>>> m.group()
'http://some-server.com/with1234init.also'
```

1. the pattern used is from the web URL version in the [above link](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls)

   Note the use of the [`r`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix) prefix and the escaped `'` quote towards the end in the first pattern.
2. using [re.compile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) caches the regex pattern